# Adding links to pdf by using MigraDoc

Tags: c#, pdf, hyperlink, migradoc

I use MigraDoc for creating pdf documents in the project.

Code below shows how I work with library:

```
        var document = new Document { Info = { Author = "title" } };
        Section section = document.AddSection();
        Paragraph paragraph = section.AddParagraph("Title");
        var renderer = new PdfDocumentRenderer(true, PdfSharp.Pdf.PdfFontEmbedding.Always) { Document = document };
        renderer.RenderDocument();
```

So, I'm looking for a way to adding link to web resource inside pdf.

Does someone know?)

-------------Solution-------------------

I found solution!

I tried to use AddHyperlink() for adding link, and it was the first step for this. The code below shows correct using:

```
        var h = paragraph.AddHyperlink("http://stackoverflow.com/",HyperlinkType.Web);
        h.AddFormattedText("http://www.stackoverflow.com/");
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To add a link use AddHyperlink():

```
    var h = paragraph.AddHyperlink("http://stackoverflow.com/",HyperlinkType.Web);
    h.AddFormattedText("http://www.stackoverflow.com/");
```

So the idea that you should add some text for a link to make link visible.

Answer (score 2):

Use `paragraph.AddHyperlink()` for that purpose. You will need `HyperlinkType.Web`.

Comment: ThomasH, I tried to use it before, but
there is no links in a document! (}
            var paragraph = section.AddParagraph("test link");
            paragraph.AddHyperlink("http://stackoverflow.com/", HyperlinkType.Web);

Comment: @BotanMan The AddXxx functions usually return a newly created object, so it's generally a good idea to check the return type. The MigraDoc samples also show how to use AddHyperlink, just see the samples site: http://www.pdfsharp.net/wiki/HelloMigraDoc-sample.ashx?HL=addhyperlink

Comment: @PDFsharp Team Yes, I found the documentation) Thanks! But I think I done it without googling if there were some comments to a method args, and why do not add separate constructor with initializing some content like a text?

Answer (score -1):

This solution worked for me where declaring a new var of type Hyperlink threw a "'Rectangle' must not be null here." exception.

```
YourParagraph.AddHyperlink("patriots.win", HyperlinkType.Url).AddFormattedText("Red Pill", _hyperLink);
```